# Rxjs, How to link up callback method to Observable?

Tags: rxjs

I need to link up a call-back method to the Observable chain.

```
private testMethod(): Rx.Observable<any> {
        const deferred = this.$q.defer();
        let promise = deferred.promise;

        this.$window.fileChooser.open((results: any) => {
            deferred.resolve(results);
        }, (error: any) => {
            this.Logger.log(error);
        });

        return this.rx.Observable.fromPromise(promise)
            .map((contentURI: string) => {
                // need to link call-back method
                this.$window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(contentURI, (absolutePath: any) => {
                    // need to pass absolutePath to next map method
                    return absolutePath;
                });
            })
            .map((fileEntry: any) => {
                let results = [];
                results.push({
                    fileEntry,
                    mimeType: 'image/jpeg'
                });
                return results;
            })
            .catch(this.ExceptionService.observableCatcher('error'));
}
```

from the promise, I can get a contentURI, and I need to call the **this.$window.FilePath.resolveNativePath** method which is using the call-back . and it should return the absolute path to next map method.

How can I link up the call-back method between returning promise and parsing map method?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`bindCallback`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-bindCallback) to create an observable for the callback:

```ts
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/bindCallback';

...
.map((contentURI: string) => {
  const bound = Observable.bindCallback((
    path: string,
    callback: (result: string) => void
  ) => this.$window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(path, callback));
  return bound(contentURI);
})
...
```

I've used an arrow function so that argument types are explicit and so that `resolveNativePath` is called on `this.$window.FilePath`.

I've not used `Function.prototype.bind`, as it returns `any` and really messes with TypeScript's inferring of the types for the `bindCallback` function.

The above answer uses RxJS 5. However, the additional information that you've added to your question shows that you are using version 4. In that version, the function is named [`fromCallback`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed).

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I got an error : _this.rx.Observable.bindCallback is not a function. do you have any idea to solve this?

Comment: You will need to explain exactly what `this.rx.Observable` is, as that is an unusual way to be referencing the RxJS `Observable`. If you use the imports in the answer, `bindObservable` will be added to the `Observable` prototype.

Comment: I've updated the answer. The answer uses RxJS version 5, but you appear to be using version 4. The function was [renamed between versions](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#operators-renamed-or-removed).